# C++ Constructor undefined

Tags: c++, cmake

I work on C++ project, i use CMake to build my file. My build fail cause

> undefined reference to `Software::Software()'

, but I do not see the problem. If you have an idea, do not hesitate, thank you

Files architecture:

[image]

CMake :

```
# cmake_minimum_required(VERSION <specify CMake version here>)
project(untitled)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(include)

file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")
add_executable(untitled ${SOURCES})
```

Software.h :

```
#include <string>
class Software{
    private : 
        std::string name;

    public :
        Software();
}
```

Software.cpp :

```
#include "Software.h"

Software::Software() {
    this->name = "defaultName";
}
```

SoftwaresConfigurations.h (who call the contructor of Software) :

```
#include "Software.h"

class SoftwaresConfigurations {
    public:
        SoftwaresConfigurations();
}
```

SoftwaresConfiguration.cpp :

```
#include "SoftwaresConfigurations.h"

SoftwaresConfigurations::SoftwaresConfigurations(){
    Software software = Software();
}
```

Comment: Either use `Software* software = new Software();` for dynamically allocated variables or `Software software;` for variables on the stack

Comment: @vre There is nothing inherently wrong with `Software software = Software();`. It is just redundant.

Comment: Did you do the required debugging yourself? Basic things like adding a `message` that prints `SOURCES`?

Comment: @vre your suggestion is rather misleading. Please dont suggest others to use `new` when there is no reason to do so

Comment: Ok, I going to change it sorry, i going to put a github link

Comment: No please dont put a link. Please do read about [mcve]! We need a complete verifiable example in the question

Comment: @StoryTeller adding said message would have magically fixed the issue, actually :)

Comment: @Botje - Making it a Schrödinger's bug? :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have fallen into the trap that is `FILE(GLOB ...)`.
Re-running CMake should fix this, but you should probably move away from using GLOB to collect your source files. For example, you can list them explicitly as follows:

```
set(SOURCES src/main.cpp src/Softwares.cpp src/SoftwaresConfigurations.cpp)
```

I will explain what happened below.

The official documentation says the following:

> We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate.

So what probably happened is that you created the project with just one source file. CMake ran the `GLOB` at configuration-time and found only the one .cpp file.
Then, you added two files (which CMake did not know about) and added the `#include` to your `SoftwaresConfiguration.cpp`. This triggers a rebuild. However, since CMake does not know about `Softwares.cpp`, it does not build that file and the linker produces an unreferenced symbol.

Comment: ok but if i do it i need to add each time my new `.cpp` file ?

Comment: Yes, you need to add each new .cpp file to your CMakeLists.txt. It is annoying, but you get used to it. I think an IDE like CLion should offer to update the list for you though.

Comment: Adding every single file is the best approach, even in the case some files are target specific.

    `if("${PLATFORM}" STREQUAL "arm")
        set(SRC
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/arm_platform.cpp
        )
    else()
        set(SRC
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/x86_platform.cpp
        )
    endif()`

Comment: @Th.Thielemann I would `LIST(APPEND SRC ...)` instead, but good remark!

Comment: @Botje I would `target_sources(target PRIVATE ...)` instead, but good remark!

Comment: BTW, I add every single cpp file even for projects with 2 thousand cpp files.